# Remove selected from checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I've looked up many things and taken many suggestions, but for some reason can't seem to figure out why this code is not working to remove the selected items from my checkboxlist:

```
void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < UPCList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (UPCList.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                UPCList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }

        }
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?account=" + AcctNum.Text);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Are you populating the list from the database?  What method is that in?  Is `WebForm2.aspx` the same page, or a different page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a big case of PICNIC :) The items were in a database, so when the page refreshed, it just retrieved the items I "deleted" again. Once I removed them from the db, all was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
List<ListItem> toBeRemoved = new List<ListItem>();
for(int i=0; i<UPCList.Items.Count; i++){
    if(UPCList.Items[i].Selected == true)
        toBeRemoved.Add(UPCList.Items[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<toBeRemoved.Count; i++){
    UPCList.Items.Remove(toBeRemoved[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: UPCList is my checkboxlist. I do not have a second list, just the one checkboxlist. I'd like to have it where someone presses a button and all the items that are check will be removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Michael:

You cannot remove items from a list that you are iterating through.  You will want to create an array of the indexes or items to remove, then after your done looping you will then remove the items from your array.

I think @AnnArbor87 provided you the code to do this.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

What is the point of removing items from a checkbox list then redirecting?   You don't show the changes you are making

**Webform2.aspx :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<asp:checkboxlist ID="UPCList" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:checkboxlist>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_remove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="btn_remove_Click" />

    </form>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webform2.aspx.cs :**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Load";
        }

        public void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < UPCList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (UPCList.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    UPCList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }

            }
            Label1.Text = "Done";
        }
    }
}
```

Works as expected.

If I put in the

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?account=" + AcctNum.Text);
```

I get Item 1 ... 6  Remove

and a Label1 that says "Load"

also for clarity's sake i also like to do

```
  foreach (var toRemove in UPCList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(f => f.Selected).ToList())
            {
                UPCList.Items.Remove(toRemove);
            }
```

but that's just personal opinion.

Comment: I thought of that, but then when I commented that out, nothing changed, so I didn't think it was of any consequence.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < UPCList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (UPCList.SelectedIndex == i)
            {
                UPCList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }

        }
```

use this.